# ¿Como editar una contraseña encriptado de tipo Hash?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con android studio, tengo un registro de usuarios para iniciar sesión, tengo implementado el encriptado con Hash hasta ahí sin problemas me guarda los datos ya encriptados en la base de datos, el detalle es que quiero modificar esos datos y al traer esa información en campo de contraseña me trae lo encriptado tal como esta en la base de datos,hay alguna forma de ver esos datos ya desencriptado, lo que hice es borrar todo lo del campo y poner un nueva contraseña pero no me dio resultado.

**Update.php**

```
?php

  include('conexion.php');

  $idUser = $_POST["idUser"];
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $nombreUsuario = $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];


 $encryp = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

 $sql = "UPDATE t_usuario SET idUser = '$idUser', nombre = '$nombre',
 nombreUsuario = '$nombreUsuario', email = '$email', pass = '$encryp' WHERE idUser = '$idUser'";

$result = $mysql->query($sql);
if ($result) {
echo "1";

 } else {
  echo "2";
 }
 $mysql->close();
?>
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: Un hash no se puede convertir a su valor original. Por seguridad la contraseña no debería poder revertirse.

Comment: concuerdo con @Lobos el proposito de guardar el hash de una contraseña es poder compararala, si quieres editarla, en realidad debes checar primero que la contraseña sea correcta y despues permitir que tecleen una nueva...

Comment: Como bien dicen los compañeros, un hash no se puede revertir, si eso fuera posible, perdería su sentido que es garantizar la seguridad. Además, ¿qué utilidad tiene esto en tu contexto? La única posibilidad es crear una contraseña nueva. Por poner un ejemplo común, cuando un usuario olvida su contraseña, se le pide crear una nueva, enviándole un enlace a su e-mail o un código de verificación a su teléfono móvil y haciendo que responda a 3 preguntas de seguridad solicitadas al momento de haberse registrado.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces no es recomendable como administrador modificar los datos del usuario desde la aplicación, si no hacerlo desde la base de datos

Comment: No exactamente. Desde la Aplicación tú puedes ofrecer al usuario la posibilidad de **cambiar su contraseña**, en cuyo caso pedirás la contraseña antigua, solicitarás que ingrese la nueva dos veces y mandarás esos datos al servidor para que el cambio se produzca, creando un nuevo hash de esa nueva contraseña. Y puedes ofrecer también la posibilidad de **crear una contraseña nueva si el usuario olvidó la antigua**, en cuyo caso deberás generar desde el servidor un enlace que el usuario recibirá y deberá validar en su email, o un código que envías al teléfono, o ...

Comment: ... respuestas a tres preguntas de seguridad. Cuando el usuario pase uno de esos controles, entonces crearás un nuevo hash con la nueva contraseña que el usuario haya indicado. Ambas cosas se hacen en correlación, es decir, desde la App o desde el email o desde el teléfono el usuario te enviará datos y en el servidores recibes esos datos, los validas y creas el nuevo hash.

Comment: @A.Cedano digamos que el usuario dio las respuestas correctas de seguridad paso ya ese filtro, y yo como administrador ya tengo sus datos desde el formulario correspondiente y modifico o creo la nueva contraseña, el detalle es que no se si mi código php esta bien porque no me crea los cambios.

Comment: Pues dinos qué error da tu código PHP. En ese `UPDATE` te equivocas de hecho, no hay que actualizar todo como haces, sino sólo la contraseña, algo así: `$sql = "UPDATE t_usuario SET pass = '$encryp' WHERE idUser = '$idUser'";` Intenta cambiarlo y dinos qué errores da o qué pasa con tu código PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano voy a verificar gracias.